# Model binding and validation in WebAPI

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, model-binding

**Binding**

When I try to post a model via

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult DoPost(MyModel model)
```

with a simple Model

```
public class MyModel 
{
    public string Property{ get; set; }
}
```

Then the model is not being bound properly. It gets instantiated, but `MyModel.Property` is `null`. The only thing that helped is to define the model as a [DataContract], which normally doesn't seem to be required according to all the documentation (e.g. [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api))

As I want the actual representation to differ from the property name I use a name for the data member. Also I want that field to be a required field:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyModel 
{
    [DataMember(Name="property", IsRequired=true)]
    public string Property{ get; set; }
}
```

**Validation**

Now if I try to validate the Model using an `ActionFilterAttribute`, however, the IsRequired property of the attribute is ignored. The only thing that works is `[Required]`:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyModel 
{
    [DataMember(Name="property")]
    [Required]
    public string Property{ get; set; }
}
```

This leads to the next problem! The `RequiredAttribute` ignores the `Name="property"` and requires a property named `Property`, so the validation always fails if post `{ "property": "foo" }`

So what I end up with is:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyModel 
{
    [DataMember(Name="property")]
    [DisplayName("property")]
    [Required]
    public string Property{ get; set; }
}
```

This seems really awkward and I don't want to do that to all my models. Please help.

Comment: How are you posting your data? Show us your JSON. You shouldn't need `DataContract` or `DataMember` at all.

Comment: if you are getting null value in property that means something is not right with your json request.
try to create json of the MyModel using json.Net and check if that match with what you are sending to the server from ajax.

Comment: The json I'm sending is `{ "property": "foo" }`, it's exactly the result of deserialization using Json.NET. Removing [DataMember] leads to `{ "Property": "foo" }` when i deserialize. So I'd have to use JsonProperty, which won't work for xml, I recon.

Comment: @IgorLankin - can you show how model is passed to an action?

Comment: did you try [FromBody] attribute in the http post method, something like given below to fix the first problem.

[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult DoPost([FromBody] MyModel model)

Comment: @Prashant [FromBody] is the default ;)